# Changes made in raspi-config being changed back

Tags: raspi-config

Using `raspi-config` I changed my Pi's keyboard layout to Dvorak since I already use it everywhere else. After changing it I shut the Pi down because it didn't need to be on. When I came back about an hour later I booted it up and was surprised to see it boot to the command line even though I always boot to desktop. I entered `raspi-config` to change it back and discovered that the keyboard​ was now also QWERTY! I then booted it the next day and found the keyboard Dvorak and it booted to desktop showing that these changes *are* saved somewhere but didn't take affect!

Why might it be doing this and how can I get it to stop?

Comment: I'm not sure if this applies to RPi's, but from my experience with configuration files, it may be an issue with the config.  This is just a hunch, but if something in your config is invalid, it will reset the config to defaults or set it to the last working config.  Was there any instance where you had the Pi booted on Dvorak working properly?

Comment: @CMalasadas I don't understand your question, the pi has booted properly before if that is what you mean.

Comment: You might not be entering the correct setting for Dvorak, or you might be messing something else up when you enter it.